# why it doesn't capitalize it?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why in this short Ruby script it doesn't capitalize "lawrence":

```
class Player

  def his_name #the same as attr_reader :name ?
    @name
  end

  def his_name=(new_name) #the same as attr_writer :name ?
    @name = new_name.capitalize
  end

  def initialize(name, health=100)
    @name = name.capitalize
    @health = health
  end

player2 = Player.new('larry', 60)
puts player2.his_name 
puts player2.his_name=('lawrence')
```

and I get this output:

```
60
Larry
lawrence #why not Lawrence ?
```

Thanks

Comment: `puts player2.his_name #=> Lawrence`

Answer (score 3):

Your method works and it does capitalize the name, Ruby just ignores your method's return value. From the [documentation for methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values):

> Note that for assignment methods the return value will always be
>   ignored. Instead the argument will be returned:
>
> ```
> def a=(value)
>   return 1 + value
> end
>
> p(a = 5) # prints 5
> ```

Comment: thanks. to prove it I typed:
´player2 = Player.new('larry', 60)
puts player2.his_name 
puts player2.his_name=('lawrence')
puts player2.his_name
´
and got:

´Larry
lawrence
Lawrence
´

Comment: @luca use backticks to format code, see [Comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 2):

The result of the expression `x = y` is `y` and the result of the expression `o.x = y` is `y` - it doesn't matter if it is a variable assignment or a setter. (The result of a setter invoked via the above form is discarded.)

Compare with:

```
puts player2.his_name = 'lawrence' # -> lawrence
puts player2.his_name              # -> Lawrence
```